# SignalR 2.0 error /signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found) when using IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, episerver-7

I'm having some issues with SignalR 2.0 in EPiServer 7.5 (a MVC4 framework). All I get is a 404 error

> GET http://web.com/signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found)

I'm hosting everything on a Windows 2012 R2 Server. Also noteworthy is that **the solution works when running everything in IIS Express from Visual Studio but not in IIS 8.5**.

What I've done so far is to add the SingalR references.

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.System.Web, 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.OWin, 2.1.0.0
- Microsoft.OWin.Host.SystemWeb, 2.1.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin.Security, 2.0.0.0
- Owin, 1.0.0.0

**Startup.cs**

The startup is intitialized on application start so that seems  to work.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Web.Startup))]
namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        #region Local variables

        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure SignalR
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.MethodCallEntry();

                // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
                //app.MapSignalR(); // Doesn't work either
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
                };

                app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Failed to initialize or map SignalR", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger.MethodCallExit();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Script inclusion**

```
<script src="/Static/Frameworks/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Static/Frameworks/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Static/Frameworks/Scripts/modernizr.2.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Static/Frameworks/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.js"></script>
<!-- also tried path ~/signalr/hubs -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

This is not a solution updated from 1.x SignalR!

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Yea, the solution works fine in IIS Express in Visual Studio and I can debug the startup.cs as well

Comment: Please check versions of SignalR as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750727/signalr-hubs-404-not-found-after-update-to-mvc5/38985725#38985725

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error was the exact same as in this post
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2013/12/02/owin-startup-class-not-detected.aspx

The solution was to totally empty the asp.net cache

Run this in PowerShell

```
net stop w3svc
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*" -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*" -Force -Recurse
net start w3svc
```

Comment: My solutions work in various applications and host. My first app has being working for a year, but suddenly stopped working, while still work well in my local IIS. After running this script my app works again in IIS on 2012.

Comment: I think the conflicts in the cache were caused by that I removed the website directory then uploaded new content when the Website were still running. And I replicated this problem. So the lesson is to shutdown the Website before updating it.

Answer (score 18):

just wanted to put my 2 cents in.  I had this error, and it ended up being because i had

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

in my web.config.  removing this line fixed everything up for me!

Comment: I was also looking for solution for same issue, thanks a,lot Phil this also works for me. :)

Comment: Can you write your solution,becouse I have problem?

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar problem getting the "MoveShape" demo to work on a freshly built Win 2012R2 server.  I resolved the problem by adding the role/features: "Web Server (IIS)" -> "Application Development" and selecting ".NET Extensibility 4.5", "ASP.NET 4.5", "ISAPI Extensions", "ISAPI Filters" and "WebSocket Protocol".

Once I restarted the system or IIS, the demo starting working.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was resolved by removing nuget-package "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb", which was referenced in packages.config with version="2.1.0" and installing version="3.0.1".

With this version the owin environment was never started on the iis8 on server 2012r2 with the error, that the namespace "Host" was not found.

```
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.

Startup.cs(2,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Host' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Owin' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [*.csproj]
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks! Remove reference to Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb or set owin:AutomaticAppStartup to false

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same 404 problem. Ended up I updated all the DLLs except for one which was problem. I didn't update Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll

Comment: What versions did you have before and after?