# SignalR/EPiServer "/signalr/hubs?" 404 on IIS when trying to use Live Monitor

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, episerver

I'm trying to get Live Monitor with EPiServer to work.

However, when the page loads,it returns a 302 on `/signalr/hubs?`, which is just a redirect to our 404 page.

See this screenshot:
[image]

This is my startup class:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyWebApp.Web.Plumbing.OwinStartup))]

namespace MyWebApp.Web.Plumbing
{
    public class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I have installed these NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb
- EPiServer.LiveMonitor

I don't have any experience working with this; can anyone help?

Comment: Is it only `/hubs` that is broken? What happens if you try requesting `/negotiate` from a browser (e.g. http://yourserver/signalr/negotiate)?

Comment: @Pawel `/negotiate` doesn't work either.

Comment: Then it looks like a problem with the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a reinstall of the `EPiServer.LiveMonitor` package, which pulled all dependecies, including `signalr`. After that I set up live monitor again, and then tried to load the page. I still got the same result, but this time [totally emptying the asp.net cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700625/1211119) worked, as oppsed to last time.