# SignalR 2.2 returns 404 Not Found on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

I've publish my Web-Api2 on a development server (Windows 2012 Server and IIS8.5).

I've added the `Websockets Protocol` role, and also went through the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685858/signalr-2-0-error-signalr-hubs-404-not-found-when-using-iis) to make sure everything is set up on my side. The app is running under `Default Web Site'.

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 404, 
ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
   Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 09:18:54 GMT
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Content-Length: 1285
   Content-Type: text/html
}
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient
<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2
<Then>b__17(Task`1 t)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2
<>c__DisplayClass42.<RunTask>b__41(Task`1 t)
```

Do I need to add other server roles or configure IIS further?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Show the client and the server code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the client side of the application as shown from here `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException`

The status code was `404 Not Found`.

The problem was a wrong url passed to the hub connection after deploying from localhost to an actual IIS running in Windows 2012 server. Once the url was fixed, the client runs without problems.